# what is the meaning of the results saved in fast vector from Evaluation.predictions() Weka-api java

Tags: java, weka, decision-tree

When i run the j-48 decision tree classifier in my data set, i evaluate it with  fold cross validation and took the result into a fast vector by

```
predictions.appendElements(validation.predictions());
```

and i get the result as

```
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.8349514563106796 0.1650485436893204
NOM: 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.8333333333333334 0.16666666666666666
NOM: 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.8333333333333334 0.16666666666666666
.....
......
```

what is the meaning of each column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but the data that is displayed from the [NumericPrediction](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/NumericPrediction.html) class contains the following:

- Actual Value
- Predicted Value
- Error
- Weight
- Prediction Intervals

It might be a good idea to look over the Validation Set you are using and then correlate any of the above attributes with the data that is present/predicted in the Validation.